# Underfitting in CNN model

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am machine learning beginner and making a CNN model for binary text classification into 0 and 1 but model always predicts 0 or always predict 1. Used dataset size is 22000 and dataset is labeled with "0 and 1".
preprocessed dataset is as:
[image]
Code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

model_cnn = Sequential()
model_cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu',input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model_cnn.add(MaxPooling1D())
model_cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='linear'))
model_cnn.add(MaxPooling1D())
model_cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=6, strides=3, activation='sigmoid'))
model_cnn.add(MaxPooling1D())
model_cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=356, kernel_size=8, strides=4, activation='linear'))
model_cnn.add(Flatten())
model_cnn.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model_cnn.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model_cnn.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_cnn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_cnn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_cnn.summary()
from scipy import sparse
x_train = sparse.csr_matrix((x_train), dtype=np.int8, shape = (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1])).toarray()
x_test = sparse.csr_matrix((x_test), dtype=np.int8, shape = (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1])).toarray()
history_cnn=model_cnn.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=16, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Is there a way to eliminate or reduce under sampling?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not easy to compile since it is not complete but you can try using class weights and give importance to minority class in training something like this:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

#Use balanced to show we want to balance the weights based on the number of samples in each class.
class_weights = compute_class_weight(
                                        class_weight = "balanced",
                                        classes = np.unique(y_train),
                                        y = y_train
                                    )
class_weights = dict(zip(np.unique(y_train), class_weights))

# Fit the model
history_cnn=model_cnn.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=16, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), class_weight=class_weights)
```

Comment: By adding above code than error message; TypeError: compute_class_weight() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: Is there any other way to remove t underfitting.

Comment: modified. check if it works.

Comment: can you tell "train_classes" variable is for what? Did you mean training set of data?

Comment: my bad. modified. please check and if correct don't forget to upvote!

Comment: I used the modified code but still Underfitting exist.

Comment: @Michael Mezher, I used embedding layer and change the kernal size then maxpooling layer is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without example input data, but you may be inducing a single output result (likely, the majority class) due to the model being unable to extract any meaningful correlations between the input and targets.

Based on your problem and input shape, it appears your inputs are integer encoded sentences or other blocks of text (the last dimension of your input is 1, indicating a scalar representation of tokens). Unless the tokens are derived from some pretrained model/ scalar embedding space, it's difficult to see how a CNN model could learn anything of use from arbitrary integer token assignments.

If this is the case, you may have better results by inserting an embedding layer between your Input layer and the first convolutional layer.
(See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding)

To do this, you'll need to know the vocabulary size (number of unique integers across all samples) in your input/training corpus. You may wish to set the output dimension to a non-scalar value, (likely a multiple 8 to make efficient use of GPUs).

Side note -- generally speaking, convolutional architectures start with larger kernel sizes, and gradually decrease them relative to layer depth. This is because the receptive field of each convolution naturally increases each time a convolution is applied.

Comment: I edited the question for more understanding

Comment: In this case, it seems your tokens are actually sentences with minimal overlap between samples.

My recommendation: 
- Break apart each text sample into terms. Ie: "habit lowly" -> "habit" "lowly" . 
- Form your embedding layer on each unique term. (Get a list of all unique terms in your training samples, and form your embedding layer). 
- Use an LSTM or other sequence model to represent your tokenized terms in a length independent manner.

Comment: Your current approach simply won't function without major modification.

Comment: I added an embedded layer but an error occure while fitting a model. Error:  ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 800, 1) vs (None,)).

Comment: This error tells you that the resulting output of your model is of shape (None, 800, 1) whereas your labels are scalar quantities of shape (None,) (ie a vector of zeros and 1s).

Comment: To resolve this, you need to collapse the sequence length dimension. As I'd previously mentioned, you'll need to use a sequence model (such as an LSTM) to do this, or alter your convolutions such that the resulting output is a single value per sample.

Comment: I used LSTM  such as: model_cnn = Sequential()
model_cnn.add(embedding_layer)
model_cnn.add(LSTM(32))
model_cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model_cnn.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_cnn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_cnn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_cnn.summary()    .                         but model is now overfitting

Comment: But for my project i am ristricted to use CNN model

Comment: In that case, I suggest padding your sequence length to a fixed length (longer or as long than the longest sequence in your training data). You still need to break apart the sequence of terms such that meaningful correlations can be formed between your input and output). As such, your "sequence length" should be considered the number of terms in each sample.

Comment: In reference to your comment of overfitting using an LSTM, there are many approaches to mitigating this issue. Look into parameter regularization, dropout, or simply increasing your training dataset size.